# Exporting APK from react-native project

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build

I'm trying to export APK from a react-native project using this command

> ./gradlew bundleRelease

it fires this error :

```
Build file '/Users/mohsen/Desktop/fzapp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 154
```

here's the full logs from my terminal

```
trooos-MacBook-Pro:android mohsen$ ./gradlew bundleRelease

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/mohsen/Desktop/fzapp/android/app/build.gradle' line: 154

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file '/Users/mohsen/Desktop/fzapp/android/app/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file '/Users/mohsen/Desktop/fzapp/android/app/build.gradle': 154: expecting '}', found ',' @ line 154, column 10.
             },
              ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
trooos-MacBook-Pro:android mohsen$
```

What went wrong ?

Info about my environment

MAC OS Catalina
React Native version : ~0.61.5
Expo version : ~37.0.3

I used Expo first then ejected to a normal react-native project

Comment: did you  try what the log is telling you ?

Comment: @forthelulx , the log did not tell me anything ,

it just said , there's issue in a file

Comment: literally, expecting '}', found ',' @ line 154, column 10.
             },  just change that. the build messed up because of it.  A huge part of being a developer, programmer, whatever is debugging make sure you get on that asap

Answer (score 0):

You only need remove ',' after '}'

Comment: a new error :   build file '/Users/mohsen/Desktop/fzapp/android/app/build.gradle': 214: expecting '}', found '' @ line 214, column 1.

Comment: Then go to line 214 and fix that issue as well.